# How can I return a function only when the async call in a loop is completed in SwiftUI and Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I wanted to have a function that returns the list of reviews made by the user when a user is passed in as a parameter. However, I realize that the function is returning an empty array as the call to the database is only run after the function returns.

I did some search online and tried to use DispatchGroup but not sure if I'm applying it correctly.

Not sure if I'm being clear enough but here's a snippet of my code:

```
func getAllReviews(user: User) {
        let reviewID = user.reviews
        var reviews: [Review] = [Review]()
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()
        for i in reviewID {
            print(i)
            db.collection("reviews").document(i).getDocument {
                (query, err) in
                print("alive??")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if err != nil {
                        print("hello")
                    } else {
                        print("did it reach")
                 
                        let userId = query!.get("user id") as? String ?? ""
                       
                        let star = query!.get("star") as? Int ?? -1
                        let value = query!.get("value") as? Int ?? 0
                        let comments = query!.get("comments") as? String ?? ""
                        print(comments)
                        reviews.append(Review(id: i,userId: userId,  star: star, value: value, comments: comments))
                        print(reviews)
                        print("does it come")
                    }
                }
                group.leave()
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(reviews)
        }
    }
```

Would appreciate any advice, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `enter` line is at the wrong place, it must be inside the loop.

And the `DispatchQueue.main` closure is not needed

```
func getAllReviews(user: User) {
    let reviewID = user.reviews
    var reviews: [Review] = [Review]()
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    
    for i in reviewID {
        print(i)
        group.enter()
        db.collection("reviews").document(i).getDocument {
            (query, err) in
            print("alive??")
            
            if err != nil {
                print("hello")
            } else {
                print("did it reach")
             
                let userId = query!.get("user id") as? String ?? ""
                   
                let star = query!.get("star") as? Int ?? -1
                let value = query!.get("value") as? Int ?? 0
                let comments = query!.get("comments") as? String ?? ""
                print(comments)
                reviews.append(Review(id: i,userId: userId,  star: star, value: value, comments: comments))
                print(reviews)
                print("does it come")
            }
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(reviews)
    }
}
```